# Delayed Baidu Push Notification

Tags: android, push, baidu

We are implementing the Baidu push service for out customers without enabled Playservices.

Everything is working quite nicely, but I am experiencing huge delays, up to one hour.
We are located in Europe and I am testing on a Europe Samsung Galaxy S8.

The Push Notification is been sent via the Baidu Push Console, so there is no intermediate server that could delay the notification.

I noticed that there is a process running called `:bdservice_v1`. I assume that this service is responsible for receiving the notification and passing it to the main app process. How do I ensure to keep this process alive, even if the app is been killed?

**Update:**

I am revisiting this issue now and figured out, that everything is fine if the following conditions are met.

- App has been deinstalled
- Device has been rebooted
- App has been reinstalled
- Execution of `PushManager.startWork`

The delay I mentioned above is due to the execution of `PushManager.startWork` within a specific time (haven't figured out yet how long exactly). I guess that Baidu has implemented some sort of queueing and is pushing the missed notifications to the device after `PushManager.startWork`.

I also contacted Baidu support multiple times in the meantime, but haven't heard back anything. Not even an automated response!

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="xxxx" android:versionName="xxxx" package="tld.d.x" tools:node="replace" xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="18" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
    <permission android:name="tld.d.x.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="tld.d.x.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="baidu.push.permission.WRITE_PUSHINFOPROVIDER.tld.d.x" />
    <permission
        android:name="baidu.push.permission.WRITE_PUSHINFOPROVIDER.tld.d.x"
        android:protectionLevel="signature">
    </permission>

    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/d.x" tools:replace="android:label" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
        <meta-data
            tools:node="replace"
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="28.0.0"
        />
        <activity android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/d.x" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:theme="@style/DarkTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/d.x">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name=".pushnotification.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name=".pushnotification.NotificationBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="notification_cancelled" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="AmazonAPIKey" android:value="iuztgjhklöopiuzhj" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name=".pushnotification.pushServiceProviders.AdmMessageHandler" />
        <service android:name=".pushnotification.pushServiceProviders.FcmMessagingService"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="true" />
        <receiver android:name=".pushnotification.pushServiceProviders.AdmMessageHandler$MessageAlertReceiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="tld.d.x" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name=".BackgroundCmdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            ...
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="tld.d.x.file_provider_authority" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <service android:exported="true" android:name=".nfc.NfcHceService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service" android:resource="@xml/aid_list" />
        </service>-->
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="tld.d.x.file_provider_authority"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <!-- Baidu Start -->
        <receiver android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushServiceReceiver"
            android:process=":bdservice_v1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.notification.SHOW" />
                <action android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.media.CLICK" />
                <!-- Drastically improves the receiving time -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.RegistrationReceiver"
            android:process=":bdservice_v1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.METHOD" />
                <action android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.BIND_SYNC" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushService" android:exported="true"
            android:process=":bdservice_v1" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.PUSH_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.CommandService"
            android:exported="true" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.PushInfoProvider"
            android:authorities="tld.d.x.bdpush"
            android:writePermission="baidu.push.permission.WRITE_PUSHINFOPROVIDER.tld.d.x"
            android:protectionLevel = "signature"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver android:name=".pushnotification.pushServiceProviders.BaiduPushMessageReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.MESSAGE" />
                <action android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.baidu.android.pushservice.action.notification.CLICK" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Baidu Push -->
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you facing the delay if the app is in Foreground or Background ?

Comment: @Zax oddly both

Comment: @Zax Any input?

Comment: I have used a Foreground service in which i call PushManager.startWork(....), This ensures that i receive the Notifications irrespective of my app is in Foreground or background or not even started. I have also used a boot receiver which will initiate this foreground service once the device is rebooted. Thats the only work around i could find as even the latest release of Baidu library hasn't fixed this issue.

Comment: Also i always get notifications whenever my app is in foreground. Have tested in multiple devices.